# How to apply same small change to every new Git branch?

Tags: git

I'm working on a Django project whose `__init__.py` file contains a variable, `DOCUMENTS_CACHE = True`, which causes a report's output to be cached when it is run. This is the way the variable is declared in our `dev` and `master` branches.

When I am developing and testing locally, I often need to run the report many times, re-using the same inputs, to make sure the output is changing. To avoid having the report cached (and seeing the report output as it looked after the first run, despite making changes), I set `DOCUMENTS_CACHE = False`.

For each feature I work on, I create a new branch with Git based on the current state of the `dev` branch, so I'm always starting a new feature with `DOCUMENTS_CACHE = True` and I always need to manually change it to `DOCUMENTS_CACHE = False`.

I can't push this change to `dev` since it would mess things up for my colleagues.

**Questions**

How can I make this small change to each new branch I create? How do I avoid accidentally adding, committing and pushing this? The two options I'm aware of are below, but both rely on me remembering to do stuff. Is there a programmatic way to replace the `dev` version of the file in each new branch while I develop locally, and then re-introduce the `dev` version of the file before I push?

1. Manually make the change at the start, and run `git checkout __init.py__` at the end to restore it to its original state before pushing?
2. `git stash` and `git stash apply` every time I switch branches?

It may seem like I'm overthinking such a small thing, but this is my first software engineering role and I'm really trying to learn as much about Git and proper workflow as possible. Thanks!

Comment: You may be going about this the wrong way. It seems like the control knob should not be *what is in some source file* but rather something determined dynamically about the environment in which you are running. Hence perhaps you should set `DOCUMENTS_CACHE` based on the environment, rather than a constant contained in a file. That could be as simple as using environment variables, or more complex such as invoking an external program that inspects the runtime environment and returns a result.

Comment: Ahh, thank you @torek. Being relatively new to this I wasn't considering that. A good suggestion to bring to my team. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that solving this problem with environment variables is a much cleaner solution, but just for completion, here is how you would achieve this with git.

Git has hooks, which are bash scripts that run on git events. You would need to configure three.
First `post-checkout` and `post-commit`
You will want to do something like

```
BRANCH=$(git branch | grep '^\*' | cut -b3- | cut -f1,2 -d'-')
BRANCHTYPE=${BRANCH%/*}
if [[ $BRANCHTYPE == 'master' ]] || [[ $BRANCHTYPE == 'develop' ]]; then
    echo 'DOCUMENTS_CACHE = True' > __init.py__
else
    echo 'DOCUMENTS_CACHE = False' > __init.py__
fi
```

And in `pre-commit`

```
echo 'DOCUMENTS_CACHE = True' > __init.py__
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about Git hooks! Thanks so much for sharing this info. I'll mark this as the answer since I was asking specifically how to solve the issue using Git. Though for folks who may come to this in the future, the answers that suggests using environment variables may be a good solution.